# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' when converting Python file to Executable using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I used auto-py-to-exe to convert a Python script into an executable file and it converts it to an executable without any problems, but when I launch the executable the following error happens:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'*

*[11084] Failed to execute script test1*

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried many libraries to convert the Python file to and Executable and all give me the same error. I've tried with cx_Freeze, PyInstaller, py2exe, and auto-py-to-exe. All give me a *ModuleNotFoundError*, but when I run the script on the IDE it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script that runs in your IDE but not outside may mean you are actually working in a virtual environment. Pandas probably is not installed globally in your system. Try remembering if you had created a virtual environment and then installed pandas inside this virtual environment.

Hope it helped,
Vijay.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying `pip install pandas`?

Comment: Yes, I installed everything before trying to convert to exe

Comment: Tried to install pandas and compile empty program: print(panda.Series([1, 3, 5, 6, 8])), it compiled and executed without errors.

Comment: Try to add debug output and use --onedir option

Answer (score 1):

For cx_freeze, inlcude pandas explicitly in the packages. Like in the example below -

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os', 'tkinter', 'pandas']}

This should include the pandas module in you build.